# Angularjs modal service response headers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, response-headers

I am using angularjs as my front-end framework and for modals I use [angular-modal-service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service).

I would like to add response header to every .html template used by this modal service. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "add response header to every .html template "?

Comment: @GauravSharma Every time I call modal service, proper .html template gets requested and you can see it in the network panel of the chrome web console. My client wants from me to add response header to that certain request .html template.

Comment: Can you add more info about you technology stack, like what do you use to serve the HTML files?